# Symmetry of Christoffel symbols of the second kind

Tags: differential-geometry

I was reading the article: http://physicspages.com/2013/12/22/christoffel-symbols-symmetry/, and I do not understand this:

> In the locally flat frame, this equation reduces to
>
> $\displaystyle \nabla_{i}\nabla_{j}\Phi=\partial_{i}\partial_{j}\Phi \ \ \ \ \ (8)$

Even if we are considering a local frame, the basis vector still change as we move around, so the christoffel symbols seem to me shouldn't vanish. Could anybody help?

Comment: It said "In the locally flat frame", I think that's the same as $\Gamma_{ij}^k = 0$?

Comment: @John Why do you think they're the same thing? I don't think so, if you moving around a point, the basis vectors would be changing

Comment: I am not sure, but what does "locally flat" mean?

Comment: @John That's what I want to ask also

Comment: I don't like the terminology. But, given $p$, you can choose a frame field (e.g., look at Riemann normal coordinates) in which $\Gamma^k_{ij}(p)=0$.

Answer (score 2):

The term with Christoffel symbols is only needed if we are taking the gradient of a vector. However, since $\phi$ is a scalar, its value at a given point in spacetime does not depend on the basis vectors. The partial derivative of $\phi$ with respect to each coordinate is simply the infinitesimal change in $\phi$ divided by the infinitesimal change in the coordinate, regardless of the direction or magnitude of that coordinate's basis vector. Thus, $\displaystyle \nabla_{i}\nabla_{j}\Phi=\partial_{i}\partial_{j}\Phi$.